# Getting a Result Set's Column Names via T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, resultset

Is there a way to get the column names that an **arbitrary query** will return using just T-SQL that works with pre-2012 versions of Microsoft SQL Server?

What Doesn't Work:

- sys.columns and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS work great for obtaining the column list for tables or views but don't work with arbitrary queries.
- [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) would be perfect except that this management function was added in SQL Server 2012. What I'm writing needs to be backwards compatible to SQL Server 2005.
- A custom CLR function could easily provide this information but introduces deployment complexities on the server side. I'd rather not go this route.

Any ideas?

Comment: Will the arbitrary SQL always return exactly one resultset? If so you could `select ... Into` a temp table then look at the structure of that.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Sorry, a bit amature question. How to check the temp table structure? It doesn't seem to be saving into sys.tables and sp_help doesn't seems to be working on a temp table (or I do not know how to use sp_help on a temp table at least). I tried to save output into a temp table and tried this (`select t.name, c.name
from sys.tables t 
inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id=t.object_id
where t.name in ('#temp_table')`), but it doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Great idea, @MartinSmith! Would you mind turning it into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as the arbitrary query qualifies to be used as a nested query (i.e. no CTEs, unique column names, etc.), this can be achieved by loading the query's metadata into a temp table, then retrieving column details via `sys.tables`:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #t FROM (query goes here) q
SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t')
DROP TABLE #t
```

Thanks to @MartinSmith's for suggesting this approach!